# How can I display 3 monitors on Lenovo P480

Tags: display, multiple-monitors, lenovo-laptop

I have a lenovo P480 for work and I am trying to connect 3 monitors to it. 2 monitors to display port on the USB C dock, 1 monitor to HDMI on the laptop, and the laptop lid is closed.

The HDMI screen only picks up data and displays when there are no display ports plugged in. Once I plug in a display port, HDMI screen says no signal. Windows and Intel Graphics can't detect that HDMI monitor once the Display ports are connected.

The laptop is using Intel UHD 620 with 300 MHz  4096x2304@60Hz. The problem is even when I only have a display port and an hdmi screen plugged in with the laptop lid closed, it still only picks up the display port.

Any idea what's going wrong here?

Comment: Does the manual say it can do three at once? Most laptops can't.

Comment: @Tetsujin Yes this laptop can support 3. My problem is I can't even get it to support two when I do one HDMI and one DP. Once I plug in the DP, HDMI stops working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The dock's USB C cable needs to be plugged into the Thunderbolt 3 port instead of the laptop's charging port. This allocates more power to support 3 external displays. (Side effect: less power will be allocated to the dock for USB devices. This affected my RGB peripherals.)

If the USB C is plugged into the charging port, the laptop can only support up to 2 external displays.